# Dealing with 16 bit characters and char[]

Tags: c++

So in the file format I am parsing, i am reading a file into a buffer it seems every letter is 16 bits wide. When i read that into a char * and then try to print it to cout, it returns one char, I am assuming because "2." is expressed as '00 32 00 2E' i am worried its seeing this as {'\0', '2', '\0', '.'} and thinking it terminates immediatly.

Is there a trick to having 16bit chars or am i looking for a different data type?

Comment: You probably need to turn your `char` stream into a `short` stream (or `wchar` stream) by reading two characters and combining them into a `short`.

Comment: So fix your code not to do that. I'm not sure what help you want. Whatever decides when to terminate is broken.

Comment: There is no question in your question. But yes, that's why it prints only one character.

Comment: wchar i think is what i am looking for here.